# Is Multiplayer-VR in the Unreal Engine Editor possible?

Tags: unreal-engine4

the situation: Person P1 starts the game via VR Preview Mode as CLIENT. Person P2 does the same but as LISTENING SERVER. Both use the same project. The project is NOT PACKAGED and they play from the unreal engine editor.

The goal: P1 connects to P2 and they see each other moving around in the same map.

The misery: P1 tries the 'Open' command. He/She types 'Open ipOfP2' into the console, but after issuing the command nothing happens. As a result P1 and P2 get confused because the same workflow worked flawlessly when playing via standalone play (aka not VR).

MY QUESTION: Is networked-play/multiplayer from the editor supported while playing in VR preview mode?

I suspect no because I tried 3 different unreal-engine versions (4.21, 4.19, 4.11) with the corresponding VR template and nothing worked. If no, is there any way to get VR Multiplayer working without having to package the game?

Best regards, Ojad

Comment: I can't answer your question but as a fellow developer I can tell you that the editor isn't meant for in depth testing and you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Are you using the ?listen flag on the server computer?

Comment: Thanks to both of you! @BasinhetVeld We haven't appended ?listen to the end of the map name, if that's what you mean. However, our (non vr) multiplayer sessions via "standalone game" worked without having to do that. I'll try your suggestion as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in one of my own projects, and connecting to another computer in PIE doesn't work: PIE uses temporary levels with temporary names, and I think this is the reason networked computers can't connect - they can't verify the level, or resolve the (temporary) name the server chose for its level.

However - what you can do is run the server in standalone, and then connect with the client that's running in PIE. VR preview mode should work equally.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! We tested your proposal, but the 'Open' command via console remains without effect.

Comment: Even connecting to 127.0.0.1 (aka the listen server while running two unreal engine instances on the same machine) doesn't work when playing in vr-preview mode.

Comment: What messages are you log showing? Usually you can see what's causing problems in there.